# Model one to one ef6

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I have the following entities:

```
public class Application 
{
   [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
   public override int Id { get; set; }
   public ApplicationSubcontractors ApplicationSubcontractors{get; set;}
}

public class ApplicationSubcontractors
{
   public ApplicationId {get; set;}
   public Application Application {get; set;}
}
```

> I want to map this so that `Application` has an `ApplicationSubcontractors` and `ApplicationSubcontractors` has an `Application`:

How can I model this one to one?

Is the fact that the Application entity has an Id primary key a problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as shown below:

```
public class Application 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ApplicationSubcontractor ApplicationSubcontractor { get; set; }
}


public class ApplicationSubcontractor
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("Application")]
    public override int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual Application Application { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: @GertArnold Sorry I didn't get what you mentioned above ?

Comment: I mean principal/dependent. OP clearly wants `Application` to the principal and `ApplicationSubcontractor` the dependent. The latter should have an FK to the former.

Comment: Oh..got it. Corrected. Thanks a lot :) @GertArnold